# Вертикальный аккордион jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Как сделать чтобы было как на http://weibo.com

Чтобы новые элементы появлялись сверху. И область была ограничена по вертикали и горизонтали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще на предложенном сайте это не accordion, а просто новые сообщения добавляются в начало списка. Думаю вам должна помочь стандартная jQuery функция [prepend()](http://jquery-docs.ru/manipulation/prepend/)
Которая добавляет в начало коллекции элементов, а в месте с ней последний элемент нужно удалять.

Comment: Там сообщения крутятся по кругу. То ли закешированные, то ли просто выборка - не важно. Но они не напрямую из базы по одному вылазят.

Comment: Ну даже если и так, тянете из базы одно сообщение, затем prepend - добавить в начало (используя animate()) и удаляем последний `$("element :last").remove();`

Comment: Ну раз сам сделать не сможете, то подумайте прежде хорошенько - надо ли оно вам вообще